# Familiarity with KL Divergence Vectors

Tags: kullback-leibler

```
a = [2,8,10,0,3,0,0]
b = [0,0,3,4,2,0,0]
```

I would like to find out how much different the `b distribution` is from the `a distribution`. That's why I'm using KL divergence. However, the issue is that according to the original equation which one I should take as `p` and which one as `q`? In Wikipedia, `q` is written to be the reference distribution. But it is also written that `p` is the actual distribution

> "A simple interpretation of the KL divergence of P from Q is the
> expected an excess surprise from using Q as a model when the actual
> distribution is P."

Shouldn't both the actual and reference data indicate the same variable/vector here?

Comment: How would you obtain a finite value for the KL divergence in either case?  Could you explain how these vectors represent or determine distributions?

Comment: @whuber I will feed the vectors in python's scipy entropy function and it will convert them into probability distribution: dividing each element by their sums.

Comment: In that case you needn't perform any calculations, because either way you compute the KL divergence you will get an infinite result.  That's why this exercise seems like it might be misguided.